# Increasing a variable in a list error

Tags: c#

I am doing an excersise, which is a game. You are a dwarf and stones are falling down at you. For some reason I can't simply make the stones' Y increase.

I am using the following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stones.Count; i++)
{
    stones[i].y++;
    PrintOnPosition(stones[i].x, stones[i].y, stones[i].c, stones[i].color);
}
```

Comment: I am 5'11, why you called me a dwarf :P ? :D

Comment: What is the error? Can you show the code from the `Stone` class?

Comment: I think, you need to share the `stones` loop and the property y.

Comment: you don't need struct. Stone should be a class. You should be calling an update of all stones then call a visual refresh. Then lastly since you increase stones position i assume they are draw on a window because stone falling would normally decrease on Cartesian plan. So i have the feeling you might only have a problem with the refresh on the screen.

Comment: A class worked, thank you. Btw, anyone mind telling me how to show text as code here? My question has some but someone else editted it.

Comment: Edit your post and check on the tab on the right side you will see all details, also there is icons in the textbox automatically formatting selections. Typically 4 spaces start a code block

Answer (score 1):

I *presume* that `Stone` type (assuming there is one with such name) is a `struct`, so *value type*. Doing increment in such way, you just increment *a copy* of the value and not actual value you interested in.

There are number of ways to resolve this, for example:

add method `MoveDown` to struct:

```
public struct Stone 
{
    int y = 0; 

    public void MoveDown() {
       y++;
    }
}
```

so your code after this may look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stones.Count; i++)
{
    stones[i].MoveDown();
    PrintOnPosition(stones[i].x, stones[i].y, stones[i].c, stones[i].color);
}
```

Comment: You are right. Now I did it as you said, but for some odd reason the y doesn't update.

Comment: Is y a property or a field ?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to do it like this?

```
stones[i].y += 1;
```